# Plotting a 4-dimensional graph with the fourth dimension depicted using a color scheme

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, systems-biology

I wish to use Mathematica to plot a 4-D graph of R0 (basic reproduction number of a disease) against three given parameters in which the three parameters are represented by the x-, y-, and z- axes and R0 is represented by a color scheme. So, the graph will essentially look like a 3-dimensional graph, but the fourth dimension (illustrating R0) should be in terms of a color scheme.

In the current model, I wanted to plot **R0** against the three parameters **beta, p,** and **phi** which all vary between **0 and 1**. The formula for R0 and the parameters are given below.

```
c = 0.01;
gamma = 0.2;
theta = 0.2778;
epsilon = 0.084;
delta = 0.011;
mu = 0.000027;

R0 = (epsilon*c*beta*theta*(mu+(1-phi)*p))/(mu*(mu+p)*(mu+epsilon)*(mu+gamma+delta))
```

Any help on this would be highly valued. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

c = 1/100;
gamma = 1/5;
theta = 1389/5000;
epsilon = 21/250;
delta = 11*^-3;
mu = 27*^-6;

R0[beta_, p_, 
   phi_] = (epsilon*c*beta*
      theta*(mu + (1 - phi)*p))/(mu*(mu + p)*(mu + epsilon)*(mu + 
        gamma + delta)) // Simplify;
```

The range of `R0` is

```
({min, max} = #[{R0[beta, p, phi], 0 <= beta <= 1, 0 <= p <= 1, 
       0 <= phi <= 1}, {beta, p, phi}] & /@ {MinValue, MaxValue}) /. 
 r_Rational :> N[r]

(* {0, 487.406} *)

Δ = 0.1;

data = Flatten[
   Table[
    {beta, p, phi, R0[beta, p, phi]},
    {beta, 0, 1, Δ}, {p, 0, 1, Δ}, {phi, 
     0, 1, Δ}],
   2];
```

**EDIT:** Corrected scaling for `data`

```
ListPointPlot3D[data[[All, ;; 3]], 
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {beta, p, phi}), 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{beta, p, phi}, 
   Evaluate@ColorData["Rainbow"][R0[beta, p, phi]/max]], 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {min, max}}, LegendLabel -> R0]]
```

[image]

To delete data for which `R0 > 5`

```
Δ3 = 0.05;

data3 = Flatten[
   Table[{beta, p, phi, R0[beta, p, phi]}, {beta, 0, 1, Δ3}, 
     {p, 0, 1, Δ3}, {phi, 0, 1, Δ3}], 2];

ListPointPlot3D[Select[data3, #[[-1]] <= 5 &][[All, ;; 3]], 
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {beta, p, phi}), 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{beta, p, phi}, Evaluate@
    ColorData["Rainbow"][R0[beta, p, phi]/5]],
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {min, 5}}, 
    LegendLabel -> R0]]
```

[image]

```
Δ2 = 0.01;
```

Similarly limiting the range of `R0` for `data2`

```
data2 = Select[
   Flatten[
    Table[{beta, p, phi, R0[beta, p, phi]}, {beta, 0, 
      1, Δ2}, {p, 0, 1, Δ2}, {phi, 0, 
      1, Δ2}], 2],
   #[[-1]] <= 5 &];
```

Plotting with [`ListDensityPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListDensityPlot3D.html)

```
ListDensityPlot3D[data2,
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Bob Hanlon! This is great. Could you also explain how to restrict R0 between 0 and 5?

Comment: Limit in what sense? Hard limit? Or delete values outside the range?

Comment: Yes, deleting the values outside of the range.

Comment: Corrected scaling for first plot and trimmed data to R0 <= 5

Comment: Thank you so much!